# Xamarin.Forms Missing 120x120 While Uploading To Asset Store

Tags: forms, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Using Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac and trying to build my Xamarin Forms app for App Store,

Build and Runs pretty fine BUT, it gives me this error while i try to upload to App Store,

ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."

I tried every single solution with this google search: Xamarin iOS ITMS-90022 site: forums.xamarin.com

I Tried naming all my Icons according to Apple Developer Docs here: developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1686/_index.html

But Visual Studio converts naming to AppIcon-60x60@2x.png when i check the resulting ipa file.

Can someone please point me to right direction because honestly, it is driving me mad.

Thank you.

I Tried all things here: Xamarin iOS ITMS-90022 site:forums.xamarin.com
Here: Xamarin iOS ITMS-90022 site:stackoverflow.com

Expected: Upload without a problem.
Result: ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."

Comment: Please check your Icon-60@2x.png and Icon-Small-40@3x.png files. Do they have the correct format as Apple required? Try to replace them with some other images for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to this problem is, using one of the ImageCropper library, when you use a library that has iOS info.plist and Icon definitions there, it automatically overrides ( i don't know why ) Icon files and if they don't have the definition for 120x120 you get this error.

Either remove the library, or get the library source, add icon files to that libraries Info.plist aswell.

Answer (score 0):

you should check the info.plist.

```
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
<array>
    <string>AppIcon-120.png</string>
</array>
```

Comment: I am using Asset Bundle, do i have to specify icons in Info.plist even if i am using Bundles?

Comment: you should be able to fix the faulty ones by adding them manually.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't, its Xamarin problem and i am already adding ALL Icons.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all appicon in images.xcasesets and then recreate o